# How to handle IO in the Bash script correctly?

Tags: bash

I want to put a lot of filtering in a Bash script, to get my filtering commands a little shorter:

```
#before:
$ cat unreadable.log | grep "bla" |[...]| sed "s/blubb//" >>readable.log
#after:
$ cat unreadable.log | the_script_I_m_writing.sh >>readable.log
```

But how to handle the IO in the bash-script correctly, that the `after` line can be executed as shown?
As you can see inside the bash-script there will be a lot of simple commands that are piped together. All this piping should just begin with `stdin` and send the final result out to `stdout`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`cat` reads from standard input if no file argument is given.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
cat | grep "bla" | sed 's/blubb//'
```

---

Alternatively, just write a script that accepts the source file name as argument.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
cat "$1" | grep "bla" | sed 's/blubb//'
```

Use: `./script unreadable.log`.

---

In this simple case, you can also skip the `cat`, and just start with `grep`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
grep "bla" | sed 's/blubb//'
```

Use:

```
# unnecessary cat if it's just a file
cat file | ./script.sh

# get stdin from file
./script.sh < file
```

Comment: You can also skip the `grep`, since `sed` can do it: `sed '/bla/s/blubb//'` (except that the OP shows that some command(s) may exist between the `grep` and the `sed`.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson Actually, no. While the substitution is only applied to matching lines in both cases, non-matching lines aren't removed by sed.

Comment: That's easy: `sed -n '/bla/s/blubb//p'`